# Flow through a binary matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have being supplied an mxn random generated binary matrix which allows flow through the value 1 but not through the value 0. I need to determine if there is a path of flow from the top to the bottom of the random generated matrix. The 1s have to be adjacent to one another. It is for programming in Matlab.
Any reference to helpful resources on how to code the problem, or algorithm examples will be greatly appreciated.

I have some code which initially searches for the first 1 in the top row.
The code therafter searches all the surrounding positions, below and adjacent to the current 1. The flow can only move diagonally down, directly left or directly right.

The purpose i to see if there is a way, given the above restrictions, to traverse from the top to the bottom of the matrix following only the 1's

```
Random=randi([0 1],6,6)


n =0;
while Random[0,n] ~= 1
        n=n+1;
end
CoOrds = [0,n];

for i = 0:5
    if Random[i+1, n-1] == 1
        n=n-1;
    elseif Random [i,n-1] == 1
        i = i-1;
        n = n-1;
    elseif Random [i+1,n] ==1
        n=n;
    elseif Random [i+1,n+1] ==1
        n=n+1;
    elseif Random[i,n+1] == 1
        i = i-1;
        n=n+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Please fix: `while Random[0,n] ~= 1`

Comment: And all future access to `Random` to use MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Have a look at the following algorithms: [Depth-First Search (DFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and [Breadth-first search (BFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Although there might be able to use matlab build in functions to find your answer, I would recommend looking in the algorithms and trying to learn them, they are extremely useful and widespread.

Comment: @KarstenHaas there is no question. You have "how do I write an algorithm" and then an algorithm with no explanation of what you want us to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) and [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to check if a path exists:

```
lb = bwlabel(Random, 8);  %// find 8-connected regions of the random mask
st = regionprops(lb, 'BounbdingBox');  %// find bounding boxes for all regions
b = vertcat(st.BounbdingBox);
```

A valid path is a path that its boundingbox height (4-th entry in `'BoundingBox'`) equals `size(Random,1)`:

```
validPathRegion = find( b(:,4) == size(Random,1) );
```